# plot histogram of date frequencies in spark dataframe

Tags: python, date, apache-spark, pyspark, histogram

i'm totally new to spark; i have a spark dataframe like so:

```
+-------------------+----------+-----+--------------------+---------+------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|               time|  hostname|group|          mountpoint|    inode|  size|              ctime|              mtime|              atime|
+-------------------+----------+-----+--------------------+---------+------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|2016-09-20 00:32:01|sysdev4500|  scs|/zpool1/wain008/g...|       23|    92|2012-09-03 15:14:56|2012-04-10 19:08:05|2013-02-07 19:05:06|
|2016-09-20 00:32:01|sysdev4500|  scs|/zpool1/wain008/g...|       22|    74|2012-09-03 15:14:56|2011-08-09 16:16:40|2013-02-07 19:05:06|
|2016-09-20 00:32:01|sysdev4500|  scs|/zpool1/wain008/g...|189926604|167541|2012-09-19 05:47:48|2009-12-22 17:06:14|2013-03-11 20:35:19|
|2016-09-20 00:32:01|sysdev4500|  scs|/zpool1/wain008/g...|189926608|   354|2012-09-19 05:47:49|2009-12-22 17:06:15|2013-03-11 20:35:23|
|2016-09-20 00:32:01|sysdev4500|  scs|/zpool1/wain008/g...|189926601| 10580|2012-09-19 05:47:48|2009-12-22 17:06:14|2013-03-11 20:35:19|
+-------------------+----------+-----+--------------------+---------+------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
only showing top 5 rows
```

i would like to get a graphical plot of histogram distribution of the `atime`'s. what is the most efficient way of doing this on pyspark (with jupyter)? i will have literally a billion rows of data.

i also also like a CDF of the sum of the `size` of the files plotted to show much much data (in bytes) has/has not been accessed based on when the file was last accessed.

Comment: How many different `atime` values do you expect?

Comment: Same as the wordcount, but with your dates. Use a simple groupByKey or reduceByKey then plot in jupyter with bokeh